# Doing a right side join in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

First off let me state by saying I know mongo is not meant to do this and doesn't really do it, but... I have to use mongodb because of a client requirement. That being said here's my problem.

I have one collection that has the list of items. I have another collection that is rolled up hourly stats of those items. Now I need to join the two collections to get counts of the stats for each item. The issue is doing a aggregation lookup from the items collection to stats collection is very slow because the stats table is big. And I can't do it the reverse direction (aggregation lookup from the stats to the item collection example code above) because there are not zero's for hours that don't have stats. Meaning I ultimately need a list of all of my items with a list of the sum of count for yesterday and today. How can I do this?

Right now I am using aggregation lookup:

```
db.stats.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "items",
          localField: "name",
          foreignField: "name",
          as: "item_obj"
        }
   }
])
```

One more caveat is restructuring the db is not really an option.